# CSS max-height based on scroll position

Tags: html, css

Is there a **CSS only** trick to make this happen:
An element is placed in **position absolute** x,y on the screen. The document has a vertical scroll depending on its content. Can the height be controlled based on the available visible viewport area?

Exampe 1:
[image: example 1]

Exampe 2:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog">
Change my height with no JS :)
</div>
<div id="content">
... content
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8dj4xz2q/

Comment: Attach fiddle link if possible.

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is you can do this using `VH` property and also using css `calc` to calculate right height.

check out the snippet.

```css
#content{
  font-size:100px;
  color:#CCC;
}

#dialog {
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  height:calc(100vh - 130px);
  overflow-y:scroll;
  width:200px
}
```

```html
<div id="dialog">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div id="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I need it to be dynamic. I.E if the page is scrolled the height should be different.

Comment: solution which i gave you will work based on your screen resolution. do you want the height to be similar to your content in background ?

Comment: That worked fine for my use case. accepting the answer

Comment: I am glad that helped.